# how to handle multiple urls pointing to same method in Laravel4 restful controller in one Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying out a restfull controller, but binding two urls this way does not seem to work anymore. How is this best handled?

```
// in the routes file

Route::get('/,new',array('as'=>'new_bit','uses'=>'BitsController@getNew'));

Route::controller('bits','BitsController');


// the controller
class BitsController extends BaseController {

    public $restful = true;

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return "this is the bits controller";
    }

    public function getNew()
    {
        return "this is the new page";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code should be working, I suppose `get('/,new'` is a typo.

Comment: no, it is for the root and "new"

Comment: are you sure Richard? I've never seen it that way before. If you seperate it to two seperate routes, one for '/' and one for '/new' - does that work?

Comment: I guess it was possible with L3, some good features from L3 were lost in translation.

Comment: Solution suggested by Jason worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for Laravel4 thanks to JasonLewis on [Irc](http://laravel.io/irc)

```
Route::get('/{new?}', array('as' => 'new_bit', 'uses' => 'BitsController@getNew'))->where('new', 'new');
```